# How can I find the particular php-file of my Wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

How can I find the particular php-file on my server, if I want to make some changes on my website?

I have a wordpress website and purchased a theme for that. In most cases I am successful with developer tools when I klick on inspect Element. But sometimes not.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your code editor and open the theme folder located in **wp-content/themes**.

Do a global search for the element you're looking at in the Developer tools.

Please use a child theme for making changes to your existing WordPress theme, ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/